How to make Snipping Tool video not save to temp folder (Windows 11)
I am trying to record a long video using snipping tool (for Windows 11), however I do not have enough space for the video on my C: drive. I decided to save the video in another drive, the problem is that a copy is always saved into %LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\Microsoft.ScreenSketch_8wekyb3d8bbwe\TempState for some unknown reason.
If the video I am trying to record is too large, I cannot save it as it does not fit in C: drive where the automatic copy is trying to go.
Just to be clear, the copy is not going to the C:\users..\Videos\Captures folder. I disabled the Captures from automatically being saved. Even with the automatic save disabled, they still go to this odd TempState folder. (this folder that I am talking about is the one discussed in this Microsoft Q and A thread).
Any ideas how to make the captured video not go to TempState, but rather ONLY be saved in the folder of my choosing?

I would suspect this cannot be changed.  You might need to free up space or use a different recording tool.
